# Swift pod removed and now have linker error

Tags: swift3, mbprogresshud

In my Swift 3 project I have removed MBProgressHud and now have a linker error. I removed it from the Pod File and the bridging header.

```
ld: framework not found MBProgressHUD
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have run Product Clean, cleared derived data and run pod update but still get the error. I can't find it in Frameworks or anywhere else.

Build Active Architecture Only is set to YES for Debug and NO for Release. If I set it to NO for Release I get Alamofire errors.

Comment: You removed from pods and don't have the framework in the project?

Comment: That's correct, I can't see it in Frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags. After removing -framework then MBProgressHUD from both Debug and Release it compiled.